# Dynamic drop down menu structure not responding

Tags: php, jquery

I have created 2 drop down menus where the second one should be reacting to the selection of the first.

I have tested both MySQL querys and the work without any problem. For some reason it seems that page getter.php is not 'activated'. Any suggestions?

mainpage

```
<?php
require_once('includes/db_connect.php');

echo '<select id="first-choice">
  <option>Please choose here first</option>';

  $sql_lev = "SELECT
                    id,
                    klantnaam
                    FROM adressen
                    ORDER BY klantnaam ASC ";

    if(!$res_lev = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_lev)) { include('includes/error_database.php'); die; }

    while($row_lev = mysqli_fetch_array($res_lev)) {

        echo '<option value="'.$row_lev['id'].'">'.$row_lev['klantnaam'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '
</select>

<br>

<select id="second-choice">
  <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
  $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
});
</script>
```

getter.php

```
<?php
require_once('includes/db_connect.php');

$choice = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['choice']);

echo '<option value="">Choose here now</option>';

  $sql_cnt = "SELECT
                    id,
                    naam
                    FROM contactpersoon
                    WHERE klant_id = ".$choice."
                    ORDER BY naam ASC ";

    if(!$res_cnt = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_cnt)) { include('includes/error_database.php'); die; }

    while($row_cnt = mysqli_fetch_array($res_cnt)) {

        echo '<option value="'.$row_cnt['id'].'">'.$row_cnt['naam'].'</option>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is there any activity in the 'network' of your web browser developer tools when you change the select? Or any console.log errors?

Comment: I am not very familiar with those developer tools bit it seems there is no activity when changing the first select.

Answer (score 0):

Use for Seleted object with `$("#first-choice option:selected")`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
  $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice option:selected").val());
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is not solving my problem. Same result without any errors.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem at all, as what he has (referencing direct), still puts the same value in the url.

Comment: @Muiter sorry didn't see it was a select i belive your are using input :(. I made the change.